# What's the power of the following Hypothesis test?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

This is the question with all information given:

"What's the power of a hypothesis test with significance level 0.05, if the probability of picking 5 or more things from a box of 15 is larger than 50% when the probability is actually 75%?"

To be honest, I think you can interpret this in different ways, as it's ambiguous. While I've found something that could be the solution, I can't calculate it without a graphing calc (not allowed).

What do you think?

Comment: It is extremely unclear what statistic is being tested here.

Comment: I do agree. That's the exact words from the question on my statistics exam.